# TypeError with SQLAlchemy query on Ubuntu 12.04 but not on Windows

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, sqlalchemy

I have a script that I wrote for python 2.7 on a windows box. I have it working on a couple of different machines, so I know it 'moves' OK.

I am now setting up a ubuntu box (v12.04).

The same code fails in ubuntu:

```
instance = session.query(formats_table).\
filter(formats_table.c.formatid==FormatID, 
       formats_table.c.puid==PUID, 
       formats_table.c.formatversion==FormatVersion, 
       formats_table.c.formatmimetype==FormatMIMEType).all()
```

In windows it runs fine and causes no issues

In ubuntu it fails with:

```
TypeError: <lamba>() takes exactly 2 arguments (5 given)
```

What can I do to find out what's going wrong?

I am assuming that this line is being parsed as 5 different arguments, and not two (session.query) and (filter), which suggests that the brackets are not being parsed correctly?

Comment: What's the traceback look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got two different versions of SQLAlchemy.

[SQLAlchemy's `filter` method:](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter)

> `filter(*criterion)`
>
> > apply the given filtering criterion to a copy of this Query, using SQL expressions.
> >
> > e.g.:
> >     `session.query(MyClass).filter(MyClass.name == 'some name')`
> >
> > Multiple criteria are joined together by AND **(new in 0.7.5)**:
> >
> > `session.query(MyClass).filter(MyClass.name == 'some name', MyClass.id > 5)`

Note that prior to 0.7.5, you couldn't have multiple criterion in a single `filter` call -- you had to chain multiple `filter` calls to get the same effect. In your case, that would look like:

```
instance = session.query(formats_table).\
filter(formats_table.c.formatid==FormatID).\
filter(formats_table.c.puid==PUID).\
filter(formats_table.c.formatversion==FormatVersion).\
filter(formats_table.c.formatmimetype==FormatMIMEType)
```

So the "arguments" being referred to are the keyword arguments passed to `filter` -- you can only have one in the version of SQLAlchemy that ships with your version of Ubuntu, and you provide four. The other argument that you don't see is the instance object (normally called `self`) that is automatically passed when you call an instance method.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. That's a bit annoying - I got sqlal from apt-get today - I'll have to see if I can find a more recent version - having fixed the above, it now fails on another part of sqlal. I appreciate your time, thank you.

Comment: @JayGattuso [Ubuntu 12.04 comes with SQLAlchemy 0.7.4](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+package/python-sqlalchemy); you can take a look at [the changelog for 0.7.5](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/changelog/CHANGES_0_7_5) to see what exactly is different, but the number of feature additions appears fairly low, so you shouldn't have to change much.

Comment: Oh, OK - it wasn't working until I downloaded it specifically. Thank you, I'll have an explore - I'm new to Ubuntu so its all a bit of a learning curve!. Thanks.